# Execute command on second terminal in bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script to execute 2 commands at a time on 2 different terminal & original terminal wait for both 2 terminal to finish & then continue with remaining script.

I am able to open a different terminal with required command, however the original terminal seems not waiting for the 2nd one to complete & auto close before proceeding with remaining of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Hello"
read -p "Press enter to start sql installation"

for i in 1
do

xterm -hold -e mysql_secure_installation &
done
echo  "completed installation"
```

Comment: Why are you using `&`?

Comment: Thanks, I remove "&" now it's showing the next line. How can I auto close the new window once task is completed? also I noticed I get below message when the new window open up."Warning: Tried to connect to session manager, Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed"

Comment: Check out xterms's options. It looks like `+hold +sm` might do what you want (get rid of `-hold`). https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.7.0/doc/xterm.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bash `wait` command to cause the calling script to wait for a background process to complete. Your `for` loop implies that you may be launching multiple background processes in parallel even though in your question there's only one. Without any options `wait` will wait for all of them.

I wonder why you're launching the processes in `xterm` instead of directly.